# not able to change the width and height of primeng pie chart , bar chart and line chart?

Tags: charts, primeng

I am using primeng pie chart , line chart ,  bar chart in my application. I was able to  change the width and height before updating the primeng version to "primeng": "^5.2.0-rc.1".

It was working fine in the earlier version. After updating the version, width and height of these charts are not working. Can you please help me resolve this issue?

```
html:
 <p-chart type="pie"  [data]="piedata" [width]="600" [height]="600" [options]="pieOptions"></p-chart>

component.ts
this.piedata = {
                labels: this.chartGroupList,
                datasets: [{
                                data: this.itemCountList,
                                backgroundColor:this.itemColorList,
                                hoverBackgroundColor:this.itemColorList
                            }]
                };

   pieOptions = {
        responsive: false,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
    };
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It worked after removing the [options].

```
<p-chart type="pie" width="550px" height="550px" [data]="piedata"></p-chart>
```